# "/usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" on Debian. How can I restore or reconfigure perl?

Tags: linux, debian, perl

**Short Question:**

It seems that I have problems with perl, which makes me unable to run the `dpkg-reconfigure` command. How to recover the `/usr/bin/perl` file?

**Some Background**

I have had some problems with my GUI and I am trying to resolve it with the help of the dpkg package manager, however, I can not execute the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` command, for example, it gives me `bash: /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.

I do not know much about perl, but as in the dpkg-reconfigure header there is a link to /usr/bin/perl, I searched for the file and it is not there.

The `which perl` command gives me nothing.

I'll put down the output for the command `dpkg --configure -a`

```
root@pc:/# dpkg --configure -a
Configurando kpartx (0.4.9-3ubuntu7.16) ...
Configurando python-pkg-resources (3.3-1ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pkg-resources.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pkg-resources.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-pkg-resources (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 126
Configurando python-lxml (3.3.3-1ubuntu0.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-lxml.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-lxml.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-lxml (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 126
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de python-aptdaemon:
 python-aptdaemon depende de python-pkg-resources; porém:
  Pacote python-pkg-resources não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-aptdaemon (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
Configurando ibus-gtk3:amd64 (1.5.5-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Configurando python-six (1.5.2-1ubuntu1.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-six.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-six.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-six (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 126
Configurando python-twisted-bin (13.2.0-1ubuntu1.2) ...
A processar 'triggers' para initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 97: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: touch: Permission denied
Configurando ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork (2.18.8.13) ...
Configurando ibus-gtk:amd64 (1.5.5-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Configurando ubiquity-casper (1.340.2) ...
Configurando oneconf-common (0.3.7.14.04.1) ...
Configurando xfsprogs (3.1.9ubuntu2.1) ...
Configurando python-oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-oneconf.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-oneconf.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-oneconf (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 126
Configurando xserver-xorg-video-openchrome (1:0.3.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de software-center:
 software-center depende de python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40); porém:
  Pacote python-aptdaemon não está configurado ainda.
 software-center depende de python-lxml; porém:
  Pacote python-lxml não está configurado ainda.
 software-center depende de python-oneconf (>= 0.3) | oneconf (<< 0.3); porém:
  Pacote python-oneconf não está configurado ainda.
  Versão de oneconf no sistema é 0.3.7.14.04.1.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote software-center (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:
 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depende de python-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2); porém:
  Pacote python-aptdaemon não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
Configurando nautilus-data (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11) ...
Configurando os-prober (1.63ubuntu1.1) ...
Configurando metacity-common (1:2.34.13-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Configurando python3-crypto (2.6.1-4ubuntu0.3) ...
Configurando gstreamer1.0-x:amd64 (1.2.4-1~ubuntu2.1) ...
Configurando kpartx-boot (0.4.9-3ubuntu7.16) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/kpartx-boot.postinst: 17: exec: /usr/share/debconf/frontend: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote kpartx-boot (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 127
Configurando python3-oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1) ...
Configurando sbsigntool (0.6-0ubuntu7.2) ...
Configurando unattended-upgrades (0.82.1ubuntu2.5) ...
Instalando nova versão do arquivo de configuração /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/unattended-upgrades.postinst: 17: exec: /usr/share/debconf/frontend: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 127
Configurando libminiupnpc8 (1.6-3ubuntu2.14.04.4) ...
Configurando libgtk-3-bin (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Configurando grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.16) ...
/usr/share/debconf/confmodule: /usr/share/debconf/frontend: /usr/bin/perl: interpretador inválido: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
/usr/share/debconf/confmodule: linha 17: /usr/share/debconf/frontend: Sucesso
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote grub-pc (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
Configurando python-twisted-core (13.2.0-1ubuntu1.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-twisted-core.postinst: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-twisted-core.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-twisted-core (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 126
Configurando oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1) ...
Configurando xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.7) ...
A processar 'triggers' para libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.14) ...
A processar 'triggers' para ca-certificates (20170717~14.04.2) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates: 141: /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates: c_rehash: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote ca-certificates (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 127
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de python-twisted-web:
 python-twisted-web depende de python-twisted-core (>= 13.2.0-1ubuntu1.2); porém:
  Pacote python-twisted-core não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-twisted-web (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
Configurando libmetacity-private0a (1:2.34.13-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Configurando metacity (1:2.34.13-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Configurando python3-distupgrade (1:0.220.10) ...
Configurando libnss3-nssdb (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.5) ...
Configurando python3-update-manager (1:0.196.25) ...
Configurando libnss3:amd64 (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.5) ...
Configurando libecryptfs0 (104-0ubuntu1.14.04.4) ...
Configurando apturl-common (0.5.2ubuntu4.1) ...
Configurando apturl (0.5.2ubuntu4.1) ...
Configurando libnm-util2 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3) ...
Configurando libcamel-1.2-45 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Configurando libnss3-1d:amd64 (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.5) ...
Configurando libnm-glib4 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3) ...
Configurando network-manager (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/network-manager.postinst: 28: /var/lib/dpkg/info/network-manager.postinst: update-rc.d: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote network-manager (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 127
Configurando libnm-glib-vpn1 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3) ...
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de network-manager-gnome:
 network-manager-gnome depende de network-manager (>= 0.9.8); porém:
  Pacote network-manager não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote network-manager-gnome (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
Configurando ecryptfs-utils (104-0ubuntu1.14.04.4) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ecryptfs-utils.postinst: 10: /var/lib/dpkg/info/ecryptfs-utils.postinst: pam-auth-update: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote ecryptfs-utils (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 127
Configurando libedataserver-1.2-18 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Configurando gnome-contacts (3.8.3-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Configurando gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3) ...
Configurando libebook-contacts-1.2-0 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Configurando libebackend-1.2-7 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Configurando libnm-gtk0 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.5) ...
Configurando libedata-book-1.2-20 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de ubiquity:
 ubiquity depende de ecryptfs-utils; porém:
  Pacote ecryptfs-utils não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote ubiquity (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
Configurando libebook-1.2-14 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Configurando libecal-1.2-16 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Configurando libedata-cal-1.2-23 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Configurando evolution-data-server (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Configurando gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.5) ...
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de ubiquity-frontend-gtk:
 ubiquity-frontend-gtk depende de ubiquity (= 2.18.8.13); porém:
  Pacote ubiquity não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote ubiquity-frontend-gtk (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de oem-config:
 oem-config depende de ubiquity (= 2.18.8.13); porém:
  Pacote ubiquity não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote oem-config (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de oem-config-gtk:
 oem-config-gtk depende de oem-config (= 2.18.8.13); porém:
  Pacote oem-config não está configurado ainda.
 oem-config-gtk depende de ubiquity-frontend-gtk (= 2.18.8.13); porém:
  Pacote ubiquity-frontend-gtk não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote oem-config-gtk (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
A processar 'triggers' para libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.14) ...
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 python-pkg-resources
 python-lxml
 python-aptdaemon
 python-six
 python-oneconf
 software-center
 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
 kpartx-boot
 unattended-upgrades
 grub-pc
 python-twisted-core
 ca-certificates
 python-twisted-web
 network-manager
 network-manager-gnome
 ecryptfs-utils
 ubiquity
 ubiquity-frontend-gtk
 oem-config
 oem-config-gtk
```

Comment: Install Perl.  Although it should be there already.

Comment: When I try to install, it gives me that perl is already the newest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably deleted the perl executable by mistake. You can reinstall it by using apt-get "--reinstall" option:

```
apt-get install --reinstall perl
```

Comment: It worked, but first, because of broken dependencies, I had to follow [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed), which whas remove all files associated with the broken dependencies from /var/lib/dpkg/info/, and after this, rename the file /usr/bin/perl5.18.2 to just /usb/bin/perl. Know `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` can be performed and I can continue trying to solve my broken GUI. Thanks